# How do I remove a part of a URL with htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

So I need have this:

`http://example.com/panel/index.php?_url=/foo/bar/`

and I need to make htaccess force it to display as

`http://example.com/panel/foo/bar/` using `htaccess`.

How do I go around doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_url=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^panel/index.php panel%1? [R=301,L]
```

"?" at the end of RewriteRule need to remove GET parameters from result string.